# Vue router-view loading parents component instead of its own

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a route configuration like this:

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
        { path: 'home', components: { container: Home } },
        {
            path: 'post',
            components: { container: Post },
            children: [
                { path: 'add', components: { container: Add } }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
```

I have two `<router-view>`s, one is named `container` and the other is not named. I am expecting the `Add` component to be loaded into the `container` router-view when I visit `/post/add` . But it's loading the `Post` component. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Post.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>I am <code>./views/post/Post.vue</code></p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Does your `Post` template contain a view for `container`? Child routes are placed only in the `router-view` of its immediate parent.

Comment: @varunagarwal No, it doesn't have a `<router-view>` inside `Post`. If I add this `<router-view name="subcontainer"></router-view>` inside Post's template, immediately after the `p` tag, the `Add` component would load, but that's not what I wanted. How can I have the advantage of nested routing with a single router-view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, remove the `Post` component from the parent and add a new child component with `path: ''`. It'll look like this -

```
{
  path: 'post',
  component: // Include a component which only renders the router-view
  children: [
    { path: '', components: { container: Post } },
    { path: 'add', components: { container: Add } }
  ]
},
```

Created a [repl](https://repl.it/repls/GiganticLawngreenPortablesoftware) for your reference